# Dynamically Add Bootstrap Class to element Angular 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a page that will have a handful of input boxes that I want to be able to flag for

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="d-block">Allowance Type</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control width-150" [(ngModel)]="selectedPricingItem.allowanceTypeDescription" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon mg-batch-flag" (click)="flagItem('allowanceTypeDescription','Allowance Type')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#auditDialog">
                     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-flag" aria-hidden="true">
                     </i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have this structure a few times on the page and I want to be able to a bootstrap class (has-danger) to them based on a the click event handler I have. In that handler I am just populating an instance of a class that I intend on submitting to a web service at this point. Is the best approach to create a component with the different styles and use *ngIf to hide/show?

Answer (score 3):

Just use a class binding

```
[class.has-danger]="propWithValue"
```

where `propWithValue` should have the value `true` or `false` to get the class added or removed. There is also `[ngClass]` for more complex scenarios like adding multiple classes.

Comment: is this the best way to do it since i need to be able to control the class on multiple controls independently. this will make me have multiple variables to manage no?

Comment: If you want to have multiple elements with each their own status, then yes, you need multiple variables. Alternatively you can use an array - depending on your use case. But I don't know any other way. To store a status you need a variable.

Comment: I am thinking that a component with a property called "status" would be the cleanest. Only issue is that I would have multiple on same page

Comment: On the same page wouldn't matter. What matters is when it's within the same component.